# Update id in table from another

Tags: mysql

I've read other Questions that may be duplicates but I can honestly not understand them.

**site_news_comments.sql**   has columns id, poster_id.

**users.sql**   has columns *id, comments*.

I'm trying to run a query that does it for ALL rows in site_news_comments.

```
UPDATE users SET comments = comments + 1 WHERE id = 'ID FROM site_news_comments??';
```

But more than 1 query so it updates all users who has data in site_news_comments

Does this make any sense? sorry! How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
SET comments = comments + 1
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM site_news_comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users comment,site_news_comments ID
SET comments.users= comments + 1 
WHERE ID.users = ID.site_news_comments;
```